# How can I access class properties inside the .success of an $http call?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, typescript

I have this Typescript code:

```
class UserService implements IUserService {

    data = {
    loginMessage: ""
    };

    static $inject = [
        '$http'
    ];

    constructor(
        private $http
        ) {
    }

    authenticate = () => {

        // This works 
        this.data.loginMessage = 'Authenticating ...';

        this.$http({
            method: 'POST',
            url: '/Token',
            data: 'xxx',
        })
       .success((data1, status, headers, cfg) => {
           // Here the this.data is undefined
           this.data.loginMessage = 'Okay';
       })
    })

}
```

This is just an example but it shows my problem. I would like to be able to modify the property data inside of the .success.  However when I try to do this then it says `this.data` is undefined.

Can someone tell me how I can solve this problem.

**Update:**

Here is a solution which I found and which seems to work. I define self inside of the authenticate function. Can anyone comment on this? Is it reasonable to use this or could there be other potential problems?

```
class UserService implements IUserService {

    data = {
    loginMessage: ""
    };

    static $inject = [
        '$http'
    ];

    constructor(
        private $http
        ) {
    }

    authenticate = () => {

        var self = this;

        // This works 
        this.data.loginMessage = 'Authenticating ...';

        self.$http({
            method: 'POST',
            url: '/Token',
            data: 'xxx',
        })
       .success((data1, status, headers, cfg) => {
           // Here the this.data is now defined
           self.data.loginMessage = 'Okay';
       })
    })

}
```

Comment: This video will help clarify : https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=tvocUcbCupA&hd=1

Comment: My personal preference is more the way I did it. I don't like to nest the success function in the authenticate function because it violates the Single Responsibility Principle. What if your success function has to perform other tasks? Then is it really authenticating or is it doing something else? So if your code works, cool. But I think you can make it more readable.

Comment: Your two examples don't compile.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Something like this might work?

```
class UserService {

data = {
    loginMessage: ""
};

static $inject = [
    '$http'
];

constructor(){
    this.authenticate();
}


private authenticate(): void {

    // This works 
    this.data.loginMessage = 'Authenticating ...';

    this.$http({
        method: 'POST',
        url: '/Token',
        data: 'xxx',
    })
   .success((data1, status, headers, cfg)=>this.onSuccess(data1, status, headers, cfg));
}

private onSuccess(data1, status, headers, cfg){
       // Here the this.data is undefined
       this.data.loginMessage = 'Okay';
}
```

}

Basically, what you want is for the success function to use the `this` of the main class, correct?

So this compiles out to:

```
var UserService = (function () {
function UserService() {
    this.data = {
        loginMessage: ""
    };
    this.authenticate();
}
UserService.prototype.authenticate = function () {
    var _this = this;
    // This works
    this.data.loginMessage = 'Authenticating ...';

    this.$http({
        method: 'POST',
        url: '/Token',
        data: 'xxx'
    }).success(function (data1, status, headers, cfg) {
        return _this.onSuccess(data1, status, headers, cfg);
    });
};

UserService.prototype.onSuccess = function (data1, status, headers, cfg) {
    // Here the this.data is undefined
    this.data.loginMessage = 'Okay';
};
UserService.$inject = [
    '$http'
];
return UserService;
})();
```

Which looks correct to me (haven't tested)

Share link [here](http://www.typescriptlang.org/Playground#src=class%20UserService%20%7B%0A%0A%20%20%20%20data%20%3D%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20%09loginMessage%3A%20%22%22%0A%20%20%20%20%7D%3B%0A%0A%20%20%20%20static%20%24inject%20%3D%20%5B%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20'%24http'%0A%20%20%20%20%5D%3B%0A%0A%20%20%20%20constructor()%7B%0A%09%09this.authenticate()%3B%0A%09%7D%0A%20%20%20%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%0A%20%20%20%20private%20authenticate()%3A%20void%20%7B%0A%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%2F%2F%20This%20works%20%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20this.data.loginMessage%20%3D%20'Authenticating%20...'%3B%0A%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20this.%24http(%7B%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20method%3A%20'POST'%2C%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20url%3A%20'%2FToken'%2C%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20data%3A%20'xxx'%2C%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%7D)%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20.success((data1%2C%20status%2C%20headers%2C%20cfg)%3D%3Ethis.onSuccess(data1%2C%20status%2C%20headers%2C%20cfg))%3B%0A%20%20%20%20%7D%0A%09%0A%09private%20onSuccess(data1%2C%20status%2C%20headers%2C%20cfg)%7B%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%2F%2F%20Here%20the%20this.data%20is%20undefined%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20this.data.loginMessage%20%3D%20'Okay'%3B%0A%20%20%20%20%7D%0A%7D).

Comment: Any comment on the solution I proposed in my updated question. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

your `this` inside the function isn't the service, but the function(read about function scope).
Use a local `self` var for that.

```
  constructor(private $http) {
    var self = this; // add this
  }

 authenticate = () => {
        this.data.loginMessage = 'Authenticating ...';

        this.$http({
            method: 'POST',
            url: '/Token',
            data: 'xxx',
        })
       .success((data1, status, headers, cfg) => {
           // this is the function!!!
           self.data.loginMessage = 'Okay';
       })
    })
```

Comment: thanks. I will try out your suggestion and also David's.

Comment: I tried your suggestion but it does not work. I get an error message from Typescript saying "The property 'data' does not exist on value of type Window"  also when I hover over self then it says var self: Window.  When I change the variable name to "self1" then it shows in the .success function as "could not find symbol self1"

Comment: I changed my question to show another way of doing this. Can you comment on this?

Answer (score 0):

If you define `authenticate` as a method rather than as a function, it will work. You won't need to do `var self = this;` as suggested (correctly) above.

That would make the class look like this:

```
class UserService implements IUserService {

    data = {
    loginMessage: ""
    };

    static $inject = [
        '$http'
    ];

    constructor(
        private $http
        ) {
    }

    private authenticate(): void {

        // This works 
        this.data.loginMessage = 'Authenticating ...';

        this.$http({
            method: 'POST',
            url: '/Token',
            data: 'xxx',
        })
       .success((data1, status, headers, cfg) => {
           // Here the this.data is undefined
           this.data.loginMessage = 'Okay';
       })
    })

}
```

Comment: I think it would still be undefined, since inside `authenticate`, there is the `$http` and inside its `success()` method, `this` will refer to that function, not the `UserService`

Comment: @David - thanks for your suggestion. Now that you mention it I am wonder. Is there any convention with typescript where it's more common to define methods (as you suggest) than functions ?

Comment: @David Bohunek - Right now neither suggestion work. Do you have any ideas?

Comment: It is best practise to use methods I would say. I am on phone now unable to try it myself, but if you move the code inside success function into a private method (for example called onSuccess) and call like this: .success((data1, status, header) => this.onSuccess(data1, status, header)); It will work for sure. Or you could even just pass it as a function: .success(this.onSuccess); I preffer the first option

Comment: @David - Thanks. Yes the suggestion to move it to a private method works. I would like to check it out further. When I check on the web it seems like this is quite a common problem.

Comment: @DavidBohunek - I changed my question to show another way of doing this. Can you comment on this?

Comment: Your updated version looks fine. I personally prefer using the methods whenever possible because it makes the code more readable and understandable since it doesn't require any special 'self' variables which aren't really related to what the code is supposes to do, they are just "infrastructure". Also the methods compared to inlined functions makes the code more clear imo.